# sddm does not propose desktop selection after upgrade to 18.04

Tags: upgrade, 18.04, kubuntu, kde, sddm

The system was initially installed as Kubuntu 16.04 and upgraded to 18.04 using do-release-upgrade.

After upgrade, sddm allows to log in only to Gnome session without providing alternatives.

kde-config-sddm is installed. plasma-workspace is installed, startkde is present.

How to fix it?

UPDATE1:

The system was installed from 16.04.3 Kubuntu DVD.

```
$ ls -l /usr/share/xsessions/
total 8
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   18 May  2 10:40 gnome.desktop -> gnome-xorg.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  195 May  2 10:40 gnome-xorg.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2353 Jun 30 20:29 plasma.desktop
```

Sequence of `apt update`, `apt full-upgrade`, `apt install kubuntu-desktop` haven't been changed anything.

UPDATE2:

```
# apt policy kde-config-sddm plasma-workspace

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

kde-config-sddm:
  Installed: 4:5.12.6-0ubuntu0.1
  Candidate: 4:5.12.6-0ubuntu0.1
   Version table:
 *** 4:5.12.6-0ubuntu0.1 500
        500 http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic updates/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     4:5.12.4-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
plasma-workspace:
  Installed: 4:5.12.6-0ubuntu0.1
  Candidate: 4:5.12.6-0ubuntu0.1
  Version table:
 *** 4:5.12.6-0ubuntu0.1 500
        500 http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     4:5.12.4-0ubuntu3 500
        500 http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
```

UPDATE3: removing of `gnome-session` package switched the situation to non-alternative KDE login (`/usr/share/xsessions` contains the only `plasma.desktop`). This solves the personal usage issue, but I still think `sddm` should show selection menu, as it is designed.

Comment: @DKBose because I had installed it from Kubuntu DVD. The suggested apt command set hasn't been changed anything. For xsessions, see the question update.

Comment: @DKBose Gnome is the thing I could add later, not KDE.

Comment: @DKBose `startkde` is a binary in `plasma-workspace` package. Updated with output of `apt policy`.

Comment: Your apt policy data is the same as mine. So just before the version upgrade, you could log in to either GNOME or Plasma? And you're correct about `startkde`. The locate command finds it in `/usr/bin`.

Comment: Solved for personal use by removing `gnome-session`. I can't say whether I was able to select Gnome vs. KDE on this host, but this selection was possible on another host with the same 16.04, and I'd like to see it working thoroughly.